# How do I edit "To complete this task" email in approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How do i edit this message in  "To Complete This Task" which is send to approver email in SharePoint designer after a workflow has been create.
email sample below.

[image: Here]

I wanted to edit because in the list, I'm not using title and i want it to change to other field.

Answer (score 0):

Under “Customization” click Change the behavior of a single task.

[image]

Under the “When a Task is Pending” section, find the line that says “then Email task notification to Current Task:Assigned To” and click the underlined link.

[image]

The Define E-Mail Message window opens, then you can edit the email.

[image]

Information about how to customize the approval workflow email:

http://punaro.com/2012/01/derek/modifying-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-email/